# How to remove the device's frame on Visual Studio Emulator?

Tags: android

I only need what's relevant for the development and testing. I don't need the huge "emulated" dumb bezel area mostly good for grabbing and relocating the emulator window. Even the real devices start to eliminate those bezels nowadays.

I don't need the directional clues about the device orientation it provides. Just small grabbing handle should be enough on the tool strip or in the main window.

It wastes screen real estate and makes tiling besides other useful windows hard or inefficient (even with my double monitor setup).

How can i hide or remove it?

Answer (score 11):

It no longer works: if I remove the properties (using the small trash button or leaving them empty), the manager will restore them. (My version: Xamarin.Android SDK 10.2.0.100)

But I've found another solution:

1. Open Android Device Manager from Visual Studio.
2. While your device is powered off, click the "..." in the top right corner
3. Select "Show in explorer"
4. Edit the file "config.ini"
5. Remove the `skin.name` and `skin.path` properties and save file
6. Start the device!

Comment: Thanks for the update, I can confirm that it also did the trick for me today.

Comment: Called now Reveal in explorer

Comment: Where do I locate the Android Device Manager inside VScode ? Its only there in Android studio as 'Device Manager'

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Android Device Manager from Visual Studio.
2. While your Device is powered off Click Edit
3. Find the property skinname and clear the value (leave empty)
4. Find the property skinpath and clear the value (leave empty)
5. Click Save & Start Device.

Worked for me

Comment: I had to delete the existing and create a new emulator because saving without the skin did not really "saved". Make sure that 2 skin related setting is deleted during the creation.

Comment: Where do I locate the Android Device Manager inside VScode ? Its only there in Android studio as 'Device Manager'

Answer (score 0):

**Show in Explorer** now called : **Reveal in Explorer**
And you can just add **//** before **skin** for example:

**//skin.name=pixel_xl**

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio -> Tools -> AVD Manager -> Pencil Icon next to Your Virtual Device -> Uncheck 'Show device frame'