# Remove frame from Android emulator from VSCode

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, vscode-extensions

I have both android studio and VSCode installed.However, I use VSCode for its clean user interface for flutter development. I have created a virtual device Pixel 4 on the android studio end and the same also can be launched from VScode. However, android studio has a important feature to make emulator 'Frameless'. I'm trying to configure the same feature inside VSCode but cant seem to find the settings for the same.

This stack post points to opening 'Android Device Manager' and following the steps afterwards. However, I do not know how to open the same from inside VSCode itself.

[How to remove the device's frame on Visual Studio Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947522/how-to-remove-the-devices-frame-on-visual-studio-emulator)

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can't create an Emulators from VsCode, you have to use Android Studio if you want to create one. If you want more frame on your Android Studio's emulator, you can try to change the graphic input on the advenced setting from you emulator. You can try to put on Hardware or software, choose the better for your computer configuration. If it's not better, you can try to do your own emulator with android studio.
I hope that my answer helps you.

Comment: Hi. I need to remove the frame from the emulator (make it frameless). I'm currently running VSCode android emulator with the whole frame.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A small answer is better that none